# Footer in middle of screen

Tags: html, css

For some reason my footer is appearing in the middle of my screen in between all of my content. I have the exact code for my footer on other pages and it works fine there. Does anyone have any idea why?

I already tried a lot on the internet, but the footer just will not stay in the right place.

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

.footer button {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border: 0.15vw solid #999;
  border-radius: 0.3vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25vw 0.5vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.footer p {
  padding-top: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/handel-gothic-d" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<header>
  <nav>
    <!--navigation menu-->
    <a href="index.html"> Home</a>
    <a href="making_off.html"> Making off </a>
    <!--different links-->
    <a href="plot.html"> Plot </a>
    <a href="characters.html"> Characters</a>
    <a href="credits.html"> Credits </a>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="wallpaper">
  <p class="wallpaper-text">WALL&#x2022;E</p>
</div>
<article id="homepage-intro">
  <h1><strong> Wall-E Fan page </strong></h1>
  <p>
    Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst
    Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst
    Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst
    Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst
    Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst
    Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst
    Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst Tekst
  </p>
</article>
<article class="page-content-index">
  <h3>Making off</h3>
  <p>
    Welcome to our web page about Pixar's, and maybe the world's, best ever movie, Wall-E. <br /> On here we will have a deep dive about the making off, the crew behind Wall-E, what the movie is about and we break down the most important characters. To
    get you warmed up, we have given some fun facts about Wall-E and its creator. To get started:
  </p>
  <p>
    Go to:
    <button onclick="window.location.href='making_off.html';" id="Home-page-button">
          Making off
        </button>
  </p>
  <h3>Plot</h3>
  <p>
    Welcome to our web page about Pixar's, and maybe the world's, best ever movie, Wall-E. <br /> On here we will have a deep dive about the making off, the crew behind Wall-E, what the movie is about and we break down the most important characters. To
    get you warmed up, we have given some fun facts about Wall-E and its creator. To get started:
  </p>
  <p>
    Go to:
    <button onclick="window.location.href='plot.html';" id="Home-page-button">
          Plot
        </button>
  </p>
  <h3>Characters</h3>
  <p>
    Welcome to our web page about Pixar's, and maybe the world's, best ever movie, Wall-E. <br /> On here we will have a deep dive about the making off, the crew behind Wall-E, what the movie is about and we break down the most important characters. To
    get you warmed up, we have given some fun facts about Wall-E and its creator. To get started:
  </p>
  <p>
    Go to:
    <button onclick="window.location.href='characters.html';" id="Home-page-button">
          Characters
        </button>
  </p>
  <h3>Credits</h3>
  <p>
    Welcome to our web page about Pixar's, and maybe the world's, best ever movie, Wall-E. <br /> On here we will have a deep dive about the making off, the crew behind Wall-E, what the movie is about and we break down the most important characters. To
    get you warmed up, we have given some fun facts about Wall-E and its creator. To get started:
  </p>
  <p>
    Go to:
    <button onclick="window.location.href='credits.html';" id="Home-page-button">
          Credits
        </button>
  </p>
</article>
<aside id="Fun-fact">
  <h2><b>Fun facts</b></h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Wall-E, the name of the main character of the movie, stands for Waste Allocation Load Lifter: Earth class.
    </li>
    <li>
      Wall-E was the first instance of Pixar using live-action to create a feature-length film.
    </li>
    <li>
      At the 20 minute mark, a pizza delivery truck which also appeared in Toy Story can be spotted.
    </li>
    <li>
      To learn about pure visual storytelling, Andrew Stanton, the director of Wall-E, watched every single movie of Charlie Chaplin.
    </li>
    <li>
      The font used for the navigation bar at the top of this page is the same font that was used in the Wall-E posters.
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <i> Source: </i>
    <a href="https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/trivia/?ref_=tt_ql_trv">
          Imdb.com</a
        >
      </p>
    </aside>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>
        Next page:
        <button onclick="window.location.href='plot.html';">Plot</button
        ><br /><br />Made by:
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Bart de Roos</li>
        <li>Quinten Nijsen</li>
        <li>Walter Hooijmans</li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
```

Comment: For the code that you are providing, the footer isn't in the middle of the screen. However, I would suggest not giving your footer a height if that is your footer. Just give it some padding on the top and bottom and allow it to naturally grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `height: 30vh` on the footer tag along with `background-color: #bbbbbb` is telling your website that you want that background color to only take up 30% of its container space.

Lets add an actual container inside your footer and use padding instead of height to give it space.

Hope this helps!

```css
.footer .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Next page:
      <button onclick="window.location.href='plot.html';">Plot</button
        ><br /><br />Made by:
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Bart de Roos</li>
        <li>Quinten Nijsen</li>
        <li>Walter Hooijmans</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </footer>
```